# How to retrieve ImageUri of an ImageView?

Tags: android, image, uri, imageview

I'm looking forward the method for accessing the current image's Uri from an ImageView, to save it to my database, but i've only found the setter.

Where's the getter??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no getter. Since you are the one calling `setImageURI()`, save the `Uri` to your database when you call that method.

Bear in mind that `ImageViews` do not always have a `Uri` (e.g., drawable resource, generated bitmap), which is why there is no getter.